# R: create folder using filename

Tags: r, directory

I have a folder (raw_file) that has a bunch of csv files (e.g. aaa.csv, bbb.csv). I need to create another folder (out_put) under the same directory of raw_file. Also, in the out_put folder, it will have folders that has the same name as my csv file (e.g. aaa, bbb). Can anyone show me how do this in R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming  (raw_file) is your working directory (so  setwd(raw_file)) :

```
    foldernames<-sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", list.files()) 
    foldernames<-paste("out_put/",foldernames,sep='')
    lapply(foldernames,dir.create,recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: I want to ask if your code will only work for file name that is aaa, bbb, etc... or it will work for any file names. Is "^([^.]*).*", "\\1" have something do with regular expression in Perl? Thanks.

Comment: works with any file name, sub function and regular expression is to get rid of file extensions (you can drop that if you want .csv in your folder name)

Comment: One more question. If main_folder is my working directory and raw_file directory is the subdirectory of main_folder, is there a way to get the file names of the files in raw_file (line 1) without changing the working directory to raw_file. Thanks.

Comment: yes, just add the folder-path to the list.files() function. p.e. if raw_file is subdirectory of your working directory, than foldernames<-sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", list.files("raw_file"))  does the trick.